# How to get scrollposition

Tags: list, android-jetpack-compose

How do you get scrollposition off LazyRow. is it possible in any way to get the float position of user scroll in LazyRow. I understand that you have to dceal with listState but i cant find the position inside the list state... Please help[image]

Comment: You wish to detect the position of the pointer?

Comment: no the place inbetween the scrollable indexes

Comment: Still not clear. Attach an image, preferably, and point out in that what exactly it is that you wanna achieve here.

Comment: Did so added an image hope its clearer

Comment: So you each row of numbers is a lazyrow item and you wish to detect which row and which column the user drags their pointer on? If so, not the best implementation, I guess.

Comment: nono every calendarsection so all the numbers from one to however many dates in that month is one item

Comment: and i wanna detect how close the user is to the middle so i can either go back to the last item or go further to the next one

Comment: Right, so sir, I do not believe that this is the best impl for that use-case. You wish to detect continuous drag on a lazy list,... Doesn't seem plausible at the moment. You could technically overlay a transparent `Box` over it and detect the motion there using `pointerInput` modifier, but still, not something I'd recommend. I think you should change your implementation. Have a look at Paging and stuff. I haven't built something like that so I can't tell what the current best practice is, but look up the web real quick you'll definitely find something. Do a quick search on compose calendar